# how to assign a php echo value to a variable using $

Tags: javascript, php

how to pass echo value to a variable by using php as i want to extract id and give its value to $prod.`enter code here`

```
$prodi=' <?php echo $cartr['id']; ?> ';
```

it gives me the error( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart.php )

Comment: What does this have to do with the Javascript, C and P programming languages? Or with Bootstrap?

Comment: As for your problem, are you sure you could nest single quotes? The syntax highlighting of your editor (or here on SO) should give you a hint about the answer.

Comment: @feeela seems like PHP but he uses `$prodi` as a JS variable. At least it looks like...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yep, saw that later on…

Comment: By saying *`echo value to a variable`* you mean to a JS variable? Can you please clarify?

Comment: Assuming this is about giving JavaScript variables values produced by PHP, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript) may be a better duplicate. (It would be safer to use `json_encode()`.)  If not, then I don't have a clue what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes after $prodi:

```
$prodi=" <?php $cartr = $_POST['id']; echo $cartr; ?> ";
```

otherwise you close the definition of your variable and than have a random `id`

Comment: don't take me to serious, it was kinda obvious and your offensive behavior agrees with my opinion. But this is nothing we need to discuss on so, I'm sorry for this comment, end this conversation here and now.

Comment: @FelixGaebler ah ok, I understand how my comment on Rahul's answer could come across differently than how I meant it. I deleted it now

Comment: i use the double quotes as mentioned in my question ,exatly return error

Comment: @zainulabideen I am not quite sure anymore what you are doing, but is `$cartr` supposed to be a value from a POST form(or GET of whatever)? If so, maybe the edit helped.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like given below

```
  $prodi=$cartr['id'];
  echo $prodi;
```

OR you can do with out assigning the variable

```
echo $cartr['id'];
```

Comment: @Luca No, why should you add a string inside a <php> that makes no sense

Comment: Because `$prodi` (confusingly enough) is a JS variable. (?)

Comment: If he just wants to assign the value and then echo it afterwards, this is the way to go.
@RokoC.Buljan That should be a JS-Variable? Then it kind of makes sense what he is trying to do. But how should we know if there is no explanation at all? ^^

Comment: @TobiasF. 1. because there's a `javascript` tag in the Q. 2. because that's a way to add PHP values to JS variables only by fixing the quotes.

Comment: Oh i see. Effectvely hidden i would say ^^